# Tag cloud for org files - list all tags and count the occurrences

Tags: org-mode

Is there something like a tag cloud feature for org files? Maybe something similar to the org clock table?

Or: How can I list/display all the tags used in an org document, next to the number of occurrences in the file?

Comment: Yes, thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such a thing in Org AFAIK. You'd probably have to use
some other program (R?) to produce word clouds. In any case, here's a
generic function you can use for collecting tag frequencies.

```el
(defun count-tags ()
  (let (tags count)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (re-search-forward org-complex-heading-regexp nil t)
        (dolist (tag (org-get-tags))
          (push tag tags)))
      (cl-loop with result
               for tag in tags
               do (push (list (cl-count tag tags
                                        :test #'string=)
                              tag)
                        count)
               collect
               (setq result (cl-remove-duplicates count
                                                  :test #'equal))
               finally return
               (cl-sort result #'> :key #'car)))))
```

Example:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :colnames '(freq tags)
(count-tags)
#+end_src

#+results:
| freq | tags    |
|------+---------|
|  100 | work    |
|   90 | home    |
|   80 | project |
|   40 | errands |
```